# Spivak: What does it mean that $f(z)=z^2$ wraps the circle of radius $r$ twice around the circle of radius $r^2$?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

In Spivak's *Calculus* on visualizing complex-valued functions he writes

the most common pictorial representation of a complex-valued function is provided by labeling a point in the plane with the value $f(z)$, instead of with $z$ (which can be estimated from the position of the point in the picture).

Consider the complex-valued function $f(z)=z^2$. In Spivak's *Calculus*, he says the pictorial representation of this function

> wraps the circle of radius $r$ twice around the circle of radius
> $r^2$.

and provides a picture

[image]

I am a bit confused by the quote especially. **So my question is:** is there  an explanation for what the quote means?

The picture I think I can reason about as below.

$f(z)=z^2$ takes a complex number $a+bi$ and maps it to another complex number $z^2=(a^2-b^2)+2abi$. If this is constant and equal to $k_1+k_2i$ then we get two equations

$$a^2-b^2=k_1$$

$$2ab=k_2$$

The solutions seem to be specific points. Let's find them

$$a=\frac{k_2}{2b}$$

$$\frac{k_2^2}{4b^2}-b^2=k_1$$

$$k_2^2-4b^4=4b^2k_1$$

$$4b^4+4b^2k_1-k_2^2=0$$

$$\Delta = 16k_1^2-4\cdot 4\cdot (-k_2^2)$$

$$=16k_1^2+16k_2^2$$

$$b^2=\frac{-4k_1\pm 4\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}}{8}=\frac{-k_1\pm\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}}{2}$$

For example, if $(k_1, k_2)=(4,0)$ then we end up with

$$b=\pm 2i$$

$$a=0$$

Hence, we have the points $z_1=2i\cdot i=-2$ and $z_2=-2i\cdot i=2$, and $z_1^2=z_2^2=4$.

These would be the two points annotated with $4$ on the picture.

So all the other points on the picture are obtained in this fashion, and the picture is understandable.

But what about the quote that the function $f(z)=z^2$

> wraps the circle of radius $r$ twice around the circle of radius
> $r^2$.

?

Comment: Are you familiar with *polar coordinates?* If $z = r e^{i \phi} = r (\cos(\phi) + i\sin(\phi))$ then $z^2 = r^2 e^{i 2\phi} = r ^2(\cos(2\phi) + i\sin(2\phi))$.

Comment: Ok, and how does this explain the quote from the book?

Comment: Every point on the circle $|z|=r$ is mapped to a point on the circle $|z|=r^2$, with twice its argument. So when $z$ moves around the circle  with radius $r$ once then $z^2$ moves around the circle with radius $r^2$ twice.

Comment: Ok, I see it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is best seen in polar coordinates: If $z = r e^{i \phi} = r (\cos(\phi) + i\sin(\phi))$ then $z^2 = r^2 e^{i 2\phi} = r ^2(\cos(2\phi) + i\sin(2\phi))$, i.e. every point on the circle $|z|=r$ is mapped to a point on the circle $|w|=r^2$, with twice its argument.

If $\phi$ varies over $0 \le \phi < 2 \pi$ then $2\phi$ varies over $0 \le 2\phi < 4 \pi$. So when $z$ moves around the circle with radius $r$ once then $z^2$ moves around the circle with radius $r^2$ twice.

In this sense, $f(z) = z^2$ wraps the circle of radius $r$ twice around the circle of radius $r^2$.

[image]

Comment: That's an animated GIF, but you may have to click on it to see the animation. I'll try to figure out why it does not always animate automatically.